# LinkButton OnClick is Not Frie inside Update panal

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

LinkButton OnClick(LoadDocumentVersion) is Not Frie inside Update panal here is my Code in aspx page I tried using UpdateMode="Conditional" it is not fire and asyncpostback also used it is not fire

```
<pre>LinkButton OnClick(LoadDocumentVersion) is Not Frie inside Update panal
    </pre>

         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Aspx_UpdatePanel_DocumentVersion" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">

                                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Aspx_LinkButton_DocumentVersion" runat="server" Style="float: right; margin: 2px 5px 2px 0;"  CssClass="Label_Text9"
                                                                    OnClick="LoadDocumentVersion" />
                                                                <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Aspx_UpdatePanel_DocumentVersion"
                                                                    DynamicLayout="true">
                                                                    <ProgressTemplate>
                                                                        <img src="Images/loading.gif" />
                                                                    </ProgressTemplate>
                                                                </asp:UpdateProgress>

                                                                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="float: left;">
                                                                    <tr valign="top">
                                                                        <td style="padding: 5px;" align="center">

                                                                            <asp:Repeater ID="Aspx_Repeater_DocumentVersions" runat="server">
                                                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                                                    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                                                                                        <tr valign="top" align="left" class="border_spacing">
                                                                                            <td class="Heading_border_left_spacing">
                                                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Text12_Bold" Text="<%$Resources:CRMDocument, Lbl_Attachments_FileName %>" />
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                            <td class="Heading_border_withoutspacing">
                                                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Text12_Bold" Text="<%$Resources:CRMDocument, Lbl_Attachments_Type %>" />
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                            <td class="Heading_border_withoutspacing">
                                                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Text12_Bold" Text="<%$Resources:CRMDocument, Lbl_Attachments_Size %>" />
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                            <td class="Heading_border_right_spacing">
                                                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Text12_Bold" Text="<%$Resources:CRMDocument, Lbl_Attachments_Created_By %>" />
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                    <tr valign="middle" align="left" height="25px">
                                                                                        <td class="border_left_spacing">
                                                                                            <a class="Anchor_Text9_Grey" href="DownloadAttachment.aspx?InternalPath=<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["InternalPath"].ToString () %>&amp;InternalFileName=<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["InternalFileName"].ToString () %>&amp;ExternalFileName=<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["ExternalFileName"].ToString () %>"
                                                                                                onclick='javascript:SafeHandleURL(this, "DownloadAttachment.aspx", "<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["InternalPath"].ToString ().Replace ( @"\", @"\\" ) %>", "<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["InternalFileName"].ToString () %>", "<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["ExternalFileName"].ToString () %>" );'>
                                                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["ExternalFileName"].ToString () %>'
                                                                                                    CssClass="Label_Text9" />&#160; </a>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                        <td class="border_withoutspacing">
                                                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Text9" Text='<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["Type"].ToString () %>' />&#160;
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                        <td class="border_withoutspacing Label_Text9">
                                                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Text9" Text='<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["FileSize"].ToString () %>' />&#160;
                                                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" CssClass="Label_Text12_Bold" Text="<%$Resources:CRMDocument, Lbl_Attachments_Bytes %>" />&#160;
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                        <td class="border_right_spacing">
                                                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["CreatedBy"].ToString () %>'
                                                                                                CssClass="Label_Text9" CommandArgument='<%#( (System.Data.DataRowView)(Container.DataItem)).Row["CreatedByID"].ToString () %>'
                                                                                                OnCommand="GoToEmployee" />&#160;
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                                                    <tr height="10px">
                                                                                        <td colspan="3" />
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    </table>
                                                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                                            </asp:Repeater>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </ContentTemplate>

                                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CodeBehind.cs

```
  protected void LoadDocumentVersion(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string zszFolderID = "";
                string zszDocumentID = "";
                string zszIsPublic = "";
                EMSBLCommon.AddToLog("Document", "CRM", "View Document Versions", "");
                string zszUpdateDocument = Aspx_HiddenField_DocumentPath.Value;
                string zszDocumentPath = zszUpdateDocument.Substring(0, zszUpdateDocument.LastIndexOf('/'));
                string zszDocumentName = zszUpdateDocument.Substring(zszUpdateDocument.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                zszFolderID = GetFolderID(zszDocumentPath, ref zszIsPublic);
                zszDocumentID = EMSBLCRM.GetDocumentID(zszFolderID, zszDocumentName).ToString();
                if (!zszDocumentID.Equals("0"))
                    LoadDocumentAttachments(zszDocumentID);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utilities.SendCrashEMail(ref ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: where is your code behind?

Comment: Have you add ScriptManager control to your .aspx file?

Comment: Your update panel will not work without it!!! Add following line before your update panel: <asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />

Comment: I added this because i am using telerik then also its not working

Comment: <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />

Comment: I don't see Telerik controls in your page!!

Comment: Also you can't set ID of any control as reserved names; you can't use *ScriptManager* as ID, caz' it is *CONTROL*.

Comment: It is a basic rule of any programming language. You didn't know about that?

Comment: I Used all scenarios u mentioned in Above its Not Working

Comment: did you try to debug? Your function does not working or linkbutton is not firing?

Comment: also remove UpdateMode from your updatepanel, you don't need that in your case

Comment: i Removed Then also its not Working

Comment: You read only last comment??? I asked "did you try to debug? Your method does not works or linkbutton does not fires?"

Comment: when i put breakpoint on Page_load its Firing,when I put breakpoint in LoadDocumentVersion function its not firing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `AutoEventWireup="true"` in your Page directive
2. Make sure you do not get errors, either client-side or server-side. Attach a debugger and step through your code to make sure of that
3. Your button cannot be clicked as it is because it is invisible, so I assume you invoke the click via JavaScript. To do that for a link button, you need to evaluate its href attribute: `eval(document.getElementById("<%=Aspx_LinkButton_DocumentVersion.ClientID%>").getAttribute("href"));`
4. make sure all webresource requests pass (i.e., 200 or 300s status codes). This is how the MS AJAX frameworks is fetched.
5. Make sure your script manager is the first control after the `<form>` tag and that all subsequent AJAX-enabled stuff is inside the `<form>` as well.